# How to work on an Oracle Apex application on two different computers at the same time?

Tags: localhost, oracle-apex

I have recently installed Oracle Apex and has been testing it out on my desktop using localhost. I am wondering if it is possible for me to access the same workspace and application on another device of mine and sync all my activities on both devices. Any advice or help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: If it's on the same network, then I think you'll be fine? I'm sure I've done this, and had my smart phone also running pages off my PC localhost.

Comment: Could you possibly tell me how to run pages from PC localhost on the smart phone? It'd be great help. Thanks!

Comment: `localhost` is just an alias for the IP address of the computer you're working on. To access it from another computer, you'd use the IP address instead.

Comment: Would I use my public or local IP address?

Answer (score 0):

you just need to access your IP address and port : from any other browser in the same network. It's the same as Express or any other web server. If you have any firewall or two different networks then there's nothing to do with Oracle APEX.

Comment: Would simply http://localhost:8080/apex work on different computers in the same network or do I have to do http://myIpAddress/apex? I just tried to type http://myIpAddress:8080/apex to access the login page, but it said that the page was not responding.

Comment: I also tried to use my local ip address to access the login page, that did allow me to login and all, but doesn't every device have a different local ip address?

Comment: Yes, each device should have a different IP address, unique within your local network.